# Defence against stealth bombers?

Tags: civilization-5

I was fighting a technological superior foe. Korea!  had only just gained Jet technology.

Korea had employed a stealth bomber. For once I was on the wrong side of this weapon and Korea was picking off my melee units.

In the city i was attacking from/defending I had jet fighters set to intercept . I also had an anti-aircraft gun. I am not sure if I was damaging the Stealth Bomber.

I had quick combat on which could have made it difficult to see if I was damaging the bomber.

Can stealth bombers be defended from? (other than from the bomber taking a little damage as you do attacking any target with planes).

Comment: Excellent question. The best counter I can think of is to conquer or nuke the cities in which they are based, but they have such a long range it can be problematic. I hope you find some decent answer!

Comment: Not long enough for an answer: Pillage their aluminium with infantry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to defend against Stealth Bombers is capture the city they are based from or to damage them so much using nuclear weapons that they are destroyed. The later being the most effective option as the air unit would most likely relocate prior to conventional invasion.

The reason that air defences do not work is because the Stealth Bomber has this ability:

```
Evasion (100)
```

100 evasion is 100% evasion. This means that fighters/jets set on interception will not intercept a Stealth Bomber and AA will not fire on a Stealth Bomber.

Answer (score 0):

Stealth Bombers have an increased ability to evade anti-air. they are however not in fact completely immune to anti-air. i would suggest turning off quick combat to see how well your anti air is doing against such a devastating unit. then build more anti-air (can never have enough in higher difficulties in my opinion).

couple proving sources for you.

[http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Stealth_bomber_(Civ5)](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Stealth_bomber_%28Civ5%29)

http://well-of-souls.com/civ/civ5_modern_units.html  <--(i would suggest Ctrl+f "stealth

bomber" for that source)

http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=395172&page=2 <---(might not be worth looking

at this drawn out forum but the answer is in there.)